# Domain and codomain of a function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, education

I am wondering if it is possible to get domain and codomain of a function in Mathematica (by using only built-in functions if possible). For example, I would like to give as input the function $tan(x)$ and to obtain the output "domain" $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + k \, \pi $ with $k$ integer, and "codomain" $R$.

Thank you so much for your willingness.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) and [`FunctionRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html):

```
FunctionDomain[Tan[x], x]
```

> 1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers

```
FunctionRange[Tan[x],x,y]
```

> True

```
FunctionRange[Sin[x], x, y]
```

> -1 <= y <= 1

**Update** on questions in comments:

- ***how the answer $1/2 + x/π ∉ \mathbb{Z}$ is related to the right result $ x ≠ π / 2 + k π $?***

The two expressions are equivalent: Move $\pi/2$ to the lhs and divide both sides of the second expression by $\pi$ to get $ x/π - 1/2  ≠ k $ ($k$ integer).

- ***Why does Mathematica return the first expression (not the second) as the answer?***

The first one is *simpler* by `LeafCount`:

```
1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers // LeafCount
```

> 11

```
ForAll[k, Element[k, Integers], x != k + π/2] // LeafCount
```

> 14

Comment: Hello @kglr thank you for your extremely clear reply. True means R or C?

Comment: @Gennaro, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: True means R or C?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, i think it means Reals.

Comment: Hi @kglr, I have another doubt: how the answer 1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers is related to the right result $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + k \, \pi$?

Comment: @Gennaro, for `k` integer, $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + k \, \pi$ iff  `1/2 + x/π ∉ Integers`

Comment: I have some problem to understand why Mathematica gives 1/2 instead of pi/2; idem for x/pi instead of k pi.